# equivalent condition on being a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let  $f: \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a continuous function.
$X_f$ - subspace of $ \mathcal C( \Bbb R^n)$ generated by
all translations of $f$, i.e. functions $ T_af(x) := f(x-a)  $, $a \in \Bbb R^n$
and dylations, i.e. $ I_cf(x):=f(cx)$ , $c \in \Bbb R$

Prove, that f is a polynomial iff $X_f$ has finite dimension.

Comment: How is $cx\in \mathbb R^n$ if $c,x\in\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: $ c \in \Bbb R $ sorry ;)